Is the data obtained from v$database in Oracle21c CDB or PDB?
I have a CDB called ORCL, which has a PDB called ORCLPDB1.
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN_MODE
--------------------
PDB$SEED
READ ONLY

ORCLPDB
READ WRITE

ORCLPDB1
MOUNTED

When I use sqlplus /@localhost:1521/orcl as sysdba to connect to CDB, execute SELECT NAME, OPEN_MODE FROM v$database;, I get:
NAME OPEN_MODE
------------------ ----------------------------------------
ORCL READ WRITE

Use sqlplus /@localhost:1521/orclpdb as sysdba to connect to PDB, execute SELECT NAME, OPEN_MODE FROM v$database;, I get:
SQL> SELECT NAME, OPEN_MODE FROM v$database;

NAME OPEN_MODE
------------------ ----------------------------------------
ORCL MOUNTED

My question is:
Why is the NAME always ORCL?
If you connect as a PDB, is the data in v$database the data of the currently connected PDB or the data of the CDB to which the PDB belongs?

v$database is primarily reading information from the database control file which exists at the "entire" database level, ie, CDB.
